# What is this shrub on the Gulf Coast?

Tags: identification, shrubs

I was in New Orleans, LA, USA this December and most plants had foliage, but this plant was bare.  What is this shrub?  It looked like it's bark was missing too, but they all look like this, see pictures. 


[image: Whole shrub view - Unknown NOLA shrub]

[image: Bark closeup with leaves - Unknown NOLA shrub]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the images shown, I'm thinking Crape Myrtle, *Lagerstroemia indica*. They are deciduous, with orange-red autumn foliage colour; the persistent, dry fruit capsules in terminal panicles are visible in the first image and the smooth, mottled trunk is typical. There are many named varieties with different size and flower colour characteristics.

[Crapemyrtle (Lagerstroemia indica)](http://www.rnr.lsu.edu/plantid/species/crapemyrtle/crapemyrtle.htm)

[Powhatan Crape Myrtle (Lagerstroemia indica "powhatan"](https://selectree.calpoly.edu/tree-detail/lagerstroemia-indica-powhatan)